# If the link is not visible in the google SERP, does it count as impressions in Google Search Console?

Tags: google-search-console, google-search

Does it count as impressions if for example I have a link appearing in the 7th page of SERP but a user did not bother checking the SERP until the 7th page?

For example in the image below, I know that I have link of my website appearing on the 7th page, will it be counted as impression even if users do not check the 7th page?

[image: Text]

Answer (score 6):

No. It doesn't count as an impression until the user goes to the page containing the link to your website.

As [Google support](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7042828?hl=en) says:

> The URL pointed to by this link records an impression when the user
> opens the page containing this result (even if the result is not
> scrolled into view). Note that the visible link URL below the title is
> not a hyperlink and so it is not recorded as impression. (Also note
> that the visible URL is not necessarily the same as the hyperlink URL
> of the title).

Answer (score 2):

The other answer covered the main search. If you're mainly worried about the CTR, I suggest checking the image results for the web keywords you're ranking for.

Google does count impressions from image search, and you may be seeing data from both combined in whichever stats platform you're using. That could skew the numbers by a lot. It's much more common to see the 70th image result compared to the 70th in web search. Google shows me 25-40 images in a single browser view (desktop), so if I scroll the mousewheel down slightly I will already be an impression on 70+ image results.

(I think this may be why Google still has separate pages and a low default number of results in web search. Maybe the advertisers complained of junk impressions on SERP ads when changes were made... hmmm.)